# When the while loop starts the code stops calculating and outputting numbers

Tags: while-loop

my code works the first time and when the loop start it stops calculating the numbers!

I want the program to ask the user to choose a material every time it finishes calculating the numbers. I used  while (1!=2) { }

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
float stress, strain, area;
double diameter;
long int F = 9900;
const float pi = 3.141593f;
int i = 0;
int main() {
char meterial;
cout << "This programm calculates the stress and strain of a rod under loads from 10000N to 20000N\n\n";
while (1!=2) 
{
cout << "Choose the meterial of the rod\n\n";
cout << "S For STEEL\nA For ALUMINUM\nC For COPPER\nT For TITANIUM\n\n";
cin >> meterial;

switch (meterial)

{
case 's':
    cout << "\nEnter the diameter of the rod in mm: ";
    cin >> diameter;
    area = (pi * diameter * diameter) / 4;


    while (i <= 50)
    {
        stress = F / area;
        strain = 200 / stress;
        F = F + 100;


        cout << "Load = " << F << "  Stress = " << stress << " N/mm^2" << "  Strain = " << strain << "\n";
        i++;
    }


    break;
case 'a':
    cout << "Enter the diameter of the rod in mm: ";
    cin >> diameter;
    area = (pi * diameter * diameter) / 4;


    while (i <= 50)
    {
        stress = F / area;
        strain = 69 / stress;
        F = F + 100;


        cout << "Load = " << F << "  Stress = " << stress << " N/mm^2" << "  Strain = " << strain << "\n";
        i++;
    }

    break;
case 'c':
    cout << "Enter the diameter of the rod in mm: ";
    cin >> diameter;
    area = (pi * diameter * diameter) / 4;


    while (i <= 50)
    {
        stress = F / area;
        strain = 117 / stress;
        F = F + 100;


        cout << "Load = " << F << "  Stress = " << stress << " N/mm^2" << "  Strain = " << strain << "\n";
        i++;
    }

    break;
case 't':
    cout << "Enter the diameter of the rod in mm: ";
    cin >> diameter;
    area = (pi * diameter * diameter) / 4;


    while (i <= 50)
    {
        stress = F / area;
        strain = 110.3 / stress;
        F = F + 100;


        cout << "Load = " << F << "  Stress = " << stress << " N/mm^2" << "  Strain = " << strain << "\n";
        i++;
    }
    break;
default:
    cout << "You entered a wrong character";
}

}

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/do3qc.png

Comment: There may an issue with `while (1 != 2)` a different approach may be in order

Comment: Please don't add textual output as an image. Also, you may want to specify the programming language somewhere.

Comment: @Jongware Its C++ sorry i didn't mention it before.

Comment: I think @Jongware knew that; I believe (s)he's suggesting that you use the "c++" tag for C++ questions, so potential answerers know if your question is one they would be inclined to address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you're resetting the value of i before the next call.

But you really should have that while loop (while (i <= 50)) in a function or method somewhere unless you have studied those yet.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` is never re-initialized to zero.  If you replace each

```cpp
while (i <= 50)
```

statement in the cases for your `switch` statement with something like:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i <= 50; ++i)
```

and remove the `i++;` lines in each corresponding block, e.g.

```cpp
    case 's':
        cout << "\nEnter the diameter of the rod in mm: ";
        cin >> diameter;
        area = (pi * diameter * diameter) / 4;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 50; ++i) // while (i <= 50) <-- change
        {
            stress = F / area;
            strain = 200 / stress;
            F = F + 100;
            cout << "Load = " << F << "  Stress = " << stress << " N/mm^2" << "  Strain = " << strain << "\n";
            // i++;  <-- remove
        }
```

your code should do what you expect.  You might consider replacing the `while (1!=2)` test with something like `while(1)` or `for(;;)`, but only because those are more common idioms (your test will always evaluate to `true` so it's still just fine).

**On Edit:** one more thing - you never re-initialize **`F`**, but you modify it in your calculation.  Each time you run through your `switch` statement, you're starting with a different initial value for **`F`**.

Comment: Probably needs a cin.ignore in there somewhere too

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yeah, you're right.  Probably also a `tolower` as well, or paired case statements (case 'A':/ case 'a':) (std::tolower might be best left for another day :)